# SQL Convert Military time to Time

Tags: sql, time, format

I have a sql database where clock in times are displayed as military time, but in number format. E.g. `907` is `09:07am`, or `1514` is `15:14pm`

Is there any way of converting this in SQL?

Currently I output into excel and use the below formula to calculate but would prefer to do all this in SQL

```
TIMEVALUE(LEFT(IF(LEN(L30)=4,L30,CONCATENATE(0,L30)),2)&":"&MID(IF(LEN(L30)=4,L30,CONCATENATE(0,L30)),3,2)&":"&RIGHT(IF(LEN(L30)=4,L30,CONCATENATE(0,L30)),2))
```

Any help you be appropriated

Thanks

Comment: Hi Jarlh Im using Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: You should use CONVERT function with appropriate format

Comment: Hi The field is varchar when i attempt to convert i get the below error The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output as a `time` value:

```
select convert(time, dateadd(second, t/100 * 60 + t % 100, 0))
from (values (907), (1514)) v(t);
```

If you just want a string returned:

```
select stuff(right('0' + convert(varchar(255), t), 4), 3, 0, ':')
from (values (907), (1514)) v(t);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon Thanks for the above im using the below formula to get the min/max date in range i have attempted the fix youve outlined but it is erroring after the from statement e.g. from emdet database ,min(CLO_TIME2) over (partition by f.CLO_DATE2,e.CDN_CARD_ID) as earliest_time

Comment: @LewisWilliams . . . This answers the question that you asked, which has nothing to do with aggregation.  If you have another question, please ask it as a *new* question, not in a comment.